# Sony DSC-RX10M3 and methods "getCameraFunction" & "setCameraFunction"

Tags: api, sony, dsc

I'm creating an app for the Sony Remote API and my DSC-RX10M3 is returning:

> error 12: NoSuchMethod for calling methods "getCameraFunction" & "setCameraFunction"?

Does my device not support these methods?

How can I transfer new original pictures and not only the postview?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't see your camera on the official list of supported cameras:

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/api-information/supported-features-and-compatible-cameras

With that in mind I would call the "getAvailableApiList" endpoint to better determine which functionality is available to you at any given time. Keep in mind that the list of endpoints available to you will change based on what mode the camera is currently in.

Also you should be able to call the "getContentList" endpoint which will give you a list of all content currently stored in the camera. This will provide a url to the content which you can then download using http.

Please let me know if you need more assistance.

Comment: RX10 III *3 ? I can take pic and postview image is fetched & Api_AvailiableApisUpdated returning AvailableApis: "getVersions", 
"getMethodTypes", 
"getApplicationInfo", 
"getAvailableApiList", 
"getEvent", 
"actTakePicture", 
"stopRecMode", 
"startLiveview", 
"stopLiveview", 
"awaitTakePicture", 
"getSupportedSelfTimer", 
"getExposureCompensation", 
"getAvailableExposureCompensation", 
"getSupportedExposureCompensation", 
"setShootMode", 
"getShootMode", 
"getAvailableShootMode", 
"getSupportedShootMode", 
"getSupportedFlashMode"

Comment: @Robert according to the API docs it is 100% supported... See attached screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/4yHFHLw. 

Is there any chance Sony are going to make developers lives easier? For a multi-billion dollar company, is it really that hard to provide API docs and information for your latest cameras (I'm really talking a7iii e.t.c. here).

People are trying to make awesome software which will only make your ecosystem stronger, but Sony (I'm sure it's not you in particular!) are making our jobs incredibly tricky! 

p.s. Thanks for making some awesome cameras mind!

Comment: Hi @simonthumper. Sorry for the late reply. I do see that your camera is supported in the pdf document so my apologies for saying that it was not. Unfortunately the camera remote API is no longer supported by Sony so for now there won't be any more updates. I do think that developers could create some amazing applications, but for now resources are being allocated for other products/experiences. Also about your question, I actually don't see cameraFunction actions in your return data. It is possible that your camera just does not support it.

Comment: @Robert that’s a shame! For a company with such huge expendable income I’d have thought you could at least write up some docs for us! I’ve documented APIs before and it wouldn’t be more than a couple of days work for a single developer... even less given it’s all basically already documented anyways! Never mind, and thanks for the reply!